# Post to phpBB from WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpbb, phpbb3

I am not searching for a bridging plugin. I have looked at those and I do not need that type of functionality.

Specifically, I need to be able to create a thread within an action hook in WordPress. I have WordPress and phpBB installed on the same server, in different databases. I have had no luck finding any code to include for authenticating / connecting to the phpBB database from outside of phpBB. Does anyone have experience with using phpBB's database outside of phpBB?

Also, do you know if it's possible to use functions from phpBB's API outside of phpBB? The `submit_post` function seems like it would work, I just need a way to get that to run within WordPress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the function call you need (`submit_post`). Check out [this article](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Adding_pages) for an explanation on how to make the phpBB API available. You could create a WordPress plugin that bootstraps the needed APIs when necessary. I wouldn't set that all up for every page. WordPress is heavy enough on its own.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I should be exiting the session after the submit_post takes place?

Comment: I don't know how phpBB works (my answer was the result of a bit of googling), but I wouldn't think you should need to worry about that. Certainly check the link I sent and follow any best practices they advise.